# Regex pattern needed

Tags: regex, preg-match

If have below text:

```
<script>

  LMS.pageData['product']['percentageDiscount'] ='26';
  LMS.pageData['product']['newPrice'] ='37';
  LMS.pageData['product']['oldPrice'] ='50.0';
  LMS.pageData['product']['savedAmount'] ='13';
  LMS.pageData['product']['price']['value'] = '37';

</script>
```

Then I need to capture newPrice and oldPrice values, please help me for Regex pattern.

thanks!

Comment: This is PHP? Or you're looking for us to write a solution in PHP to parse that for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to match:

```
\['newPrice'\] ='([\d.]*)'|\['oldPrice'\] ='([\d.]*)'|\['price'\]\['value'\] = '([\d.]*)'
```

And extract `$1` as `newPrice`, `$2` as `oldPrice` and `$3` as `value`.

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cD2rD8/13)

Comment: Can you please advise if I need to extract from below code also.
LMS.pageData['product']['price']['value'] = '19';
@karthik manchala